# In Regexp.FindAllStringSubmatch(), what does the second parameter do?

Tags: regex, go

In this method:

```
func (re *Regexp) FindAllStringSubmatch(s string, n int) [][]string
```

What does the second parameter do?
I have tried:

```
re, _ := regexp.Compile("a")
rs := re.FindAllString("aaaaa, ", **1**) // 1 get one 'a', 2 get two 'a's, 3 get three 'a's ...
for _,v := range rs {
    fmt.Println(v)

}
```

It seems that the second parameter is about how many times it matches. Am I right?
Could anybody give me an answer for sure? Official doc or some links is prefer.

Comment: Your example makes it harder to confirm the result, but try experimenting on http://play.golang.org/p/ViFmaXfEhm to see it better.

Comment: Also came here because was browsing the function level and didn't realize the info was at the top in the overview section.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Citation from the overview section of http://golang.org/pkg/regexp/:

> If 'All' is present, the routine matches successive non-overlapping matches of the entire expression. Empty matches abutting a preceding match are ignored. The return value is a slice containing the successive return values of the corresponding non-'All' routine. **These routines take an extra integer argument, n; if n >= 0, the function returns at most n matches/submatches.**

Comment: Oh, it's my fault. I just got straight to the section about the method , and skipped the overview section. I should read through it from beginning to end. I will read through it now.